# How to limit imap size in hazelcast?

Tags: java, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I would like to know when the hazelcast is loaded with some Imap object , then i want to limit its size with some number.
Tried to search it on official doc and didn't find.
Can someone tell me if there is a property for hazelcast or may be a method in Imap interface to limit with that number

Answer (score 1):

You can use eviction mechanism by setting a `max-size`. Please find the details for eviction here: https://docs.hazelcast.org//docs/latest/manual/html-single/index.html#map-eviction

Note that you can also configure a [custom eviction policy](https://docs.hazelcast.org//docs/latest/manual/html-single/index.html#custom-eviction-policy), which helps you to determine which entries will be evicted.

Comment: Thanks i will look at this